# HDMI not working 22.04, no devices found nvidia-smi

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I recently bought a new laptop with an RTX 4050, and the HDMI does not appear to work. In the "Software & Updates Additional Driver" menu, no option worked except "nvidia-driver-530-open". They would all appear to boot to a black screen with a cursor in the top left corner. However, when I run nvidia-smi, it says "No devices were found". I am hoping this has something to do with the HDMI not working.

I am a linux noob, so sorry if this is a dumb question, but does anyone have any ideas?